# APIM resource health history beyond 4 weeks

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

We've been using APIM for years, it's generally not a bad platform, pretty stable and reliable. We recently onboarded a fairly big customer and, according to the best practices of the Murphy's law, APIM went down for almost an hour on one of the first days. Which, obviously, made no one happy.

APIM has been fine and dandy before and after the incident, but the Health history only goes back 4 weeks. It would help to show logs demonstrating that it was an outlier event. Is there a way to get the Health history months or years back?

Comment: Not ootb, you will need to configure log exports to for example a storage account.

Comment: Thanks! Any pointers how?

Answer (score 1):

How about using ADF Service, I have tried using ADF, it's possible and here is the implementation details.

Using ADF - Copy data activity, I've configured for storing the Health History in the Azure Blob storage, the following workaround I did:

My APIM Instance Health History in the Portal:
[image]

1. Created APIM Instance > Added few of the Function APIs > Tested
2. Created Storage Account > Blob Storage > Container
3. Created ADF Pipeline > **Copy Data** Activity >
   **Source**: I have Selected the [REST API of the Azure Resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resourcehealth/availability-statuses/get-by-resource?tabs=HTTP) and given the API URL with its authorization header:

[image]

**Sink**: Added the Blob Storage as data set > Selected the container > Given the sample file name as `TestJson.json` as I have selected the JSON Format while mapping.

[image]

**Mappings**: Clicked on **`Import Schemas`** and added respective keys to the schema cells:

*Note: You can make Import Schemas to None so that it will add automatically all the data.*

[image]

**Validate/Run the Pipeline**:

[image]

**Result - Azure Resource Health History in the Blob Storage**:

[image]